# Software para generar lotería

Tags: java, array

estoy creando una pequeña aplicación que genera una apuesta automática en java. Al pinchar en el botón de resultados, se crear un JDialog en el que aparece la combinación ganadora y esta tendría que compararla con la que apuesta automática que he comentado anteriormente y mostrar cuantos aciertos se han producido (si es que se han producido). Mi problema, es que no consigo extraer cuantos aciertos se han producido si es que hay. Adjunto código actual de mi método numAciertos:

```
private int numAciertos(int[] premiada, int[] apuesta) {
    ArrayList<Integer> bombo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    premiada = this.premiada;
    apuesta = this.apuesta;
    premiada = new int[6];
    apuesta = new int[6];

    for (int i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
       bombo.add(i);
    }

   for(int k=0;k<6;k++){
         premiada[k]=k; 
    }

    for (int j=0;j<6;j++){
       apuesta[j]=j;

   }

    while (premiada.equals(apuesta)){
       nAciertos++;
    }

return nAciertos;
}
```

siempre me devuelve 0 este método aunque haya alguno correcto. Luego, tengo un método toString en el que muestro cuantos aciertos de x cifras se han producido, pero estamos en las mismas, si este método siempre me devuelve 0, el toString es siempre 0...

Si se necesita más código díganmelo sin problemas. Adjunto también el código con el que creo mi apuesta de manera automática

```
public int[] generaApuestaAutomatica() {
    int[] apuesta = new int[6];
    String resultado = "";

    int[] t = new int[6];
    for(int k=0;k<6;k++){
        t[k]=k; 
        t[k] = (int)(Math.random()*(49-1+1) + 1);
    }
    apuestas.add(t);

return t;  
}
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN DEL MÉTODO NUMACIERTOS**

```
private int numAciertos(int[] premiada, int[] apuesta) {
    ArrayList<Integer> bombo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    apuesta = this.apuesta;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
        bombo.add(i);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<premiada.length;i++){
        for(int k=0; k<apuesta.length;k++){
            if(premiada[i] == apuesta[k]){
                nAciertos++;
            }
        }


    } 
return nAciertos;
}
```

Después de esto, hago un toString para volcar los datos en un textArea y me muestra números sin sentido.

```
 @Override
```

public String toString(){

```
   String cadena = "";
   int contador = 0;   
   cadena +=  "0 aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n"
            + "1 Aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n"
            + "2 aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n"
            + "3 aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n"
            + "4 aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n"
            + "5 aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n"
            + "6 aciertos: " + numAciertos(premiada, apuesta) + "\n";

    System.out.println(numAciertos(premiada, apuesta));
```

return cadena;
   }

Comment: No termino de entender tu código. En el método `numAciertos` recibes en parámetro las variables `premiada` y `apuesta` **y luego las modificas dos veces dentro de él**... ¿por qué? Luego, con respecto a la comparación que haces en el `while`, si los datos son del tipo `int` no has de usar `equals` para comparar si son iguales, sino `==`... Aunque creo que `while` no es la mejor opción en este caso.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano por tu respuesta, es cierto que se me quedó código basura a la hora de publicar la pregunta, perdón. He cambiado el equals por == y ahora me muestra en el diálogo números sin sentido, creo que está generando alguna apuesta aleatoria por algún lado, ahora publico actualización de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpa, solo vi la primera parte, pero no tendría que ser algo como:

```
for(int apuestanum : apuesta)
    for(int premiadanum: pemiadas)
         if(apuestanum == premiadasnum)
              nAciertos++;
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pro no entiendo porqué usar dos for-each anidados para sacar una simple comparación de arrays, eso lo he usado para sacar elemetnos de arrayList y que sean objetos así luego poder usar sus métodos. De todas formas gracias

Comment: Perdóname @Nico54w, tenías razón era como un for-each, bien usado por supuesto. ya he conseguido extraer los elementos del arrayList, pasarlos a un array para así después poder compararlos.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, tu código es algo confuso y para lo que dices que lo necesitas no es muy bueno, la verdad.

Trataré de mostrar algunos errores claros que veo, respecto a lo que dices que necesitas.

```
premiada = this.premiada;
apuesta = this.apuesta;
premiada = new int[6];
apuesta = new int[6];
```

Primero estás recibiendo como parámetros `int[] premiada` y `int[] apuesta`, luego estos mismos los haces igual a premiada y apuesta de la clase ,respectivamente. Y luego los creas de nuevo en `premiada = new int[6];` y `apuesta = new int[6];` .

Luego a estos arreglos los rellenas con valores de 0 a 5 y usas `premiada.equals(apuesta)` lo cual creo que no hace lo piensas, el método a usar 
 sería `Arrays.equals(premiada, apuesta)` y aún así seguiría sin hacer lo que necesitas. Según entendí, lo que deberías hacer es crear un ciclo que recorra el arreglo y compare uno a uno los elementos de los arreglos y cada vez que coincidan aumente `nAciertos`.

Espero te ayude, e igualmente alguna aclaración o corrección de ser necesaria si estoy equivocado en mi respuesta.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, como he comentado con el compañero A.cedano, era código basura que se me pasó borrar... Ya he corregido eso, pero cuando muestro el JDialog, me muestra números sin sentido, como si de otra apuesta aleatoria se tratara, ya he corregido tambiñen lo del equals por ==